# Return Statement In Angular not working for an object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object, client, frontend

Pretty basic stuff... Seems like it should be working but does not

Both console logs here spit out the correct information.

```
$scope.getCurrentAttachment = function() {
  angular.forEach(attachments, function(attachment) {
    console.log(attachment);
    if(attachment.active) {
      console.log(attachment);
      return attachment;
    }
  });
};
```

But later in the file Calling it turns undefined

```
$scope.save = function() {
  console.log( $scope.getCurrentAttachment());
  var data = [$scope.labels.selected, $scope.getCurrentAttachment()];
  console.log(data);
  $uibModalInstance.close(data);
};
```

Any help would be much appriciated. I have no idea why this doesn't work

Comment: What is "attachments"?  It's not being passed into $scope.getCurrentAttachment as an argument.  Scope variable, global var, ...?

Comment: What should be working? What is `undefined`? The `$scope.getCurrentAttachment` function or the `attachment` variable? [ask] using [mcve]

Comment: the return of $scope.getCurrentAttachment() is undefined.

Also attachments is a filled array of objects that will successfully show in the log

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$scope.getCurrentAttachment = function() {
  angular.forEach(attachments, function(attachment) {
    console.log(attachment);
    if(attachment.active) {
      console.log(attachment);
      return attachment;
    }
  });
};
```

The `return` clause that you have in here, is for the angular.forEach function, not for the getCurrentAttachment .

You could do the following, using the `.filter` function from the Array ptototype.

```
$scope.getCurrentAttachment = function() {
  var filteredArray = []
  filteredArray = attachments.filter(function(attachment) {
    console.log(attachment);
    return attachment.active;

  });
  return filteredArray ;
};
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I ended up fixing my code a little differently. I just set a scope variable instead of using a return from the function. Regardless your information was extremely helpful. Thanks very much! I will accept your answer when it lets me